# C# - creating an array combination, need explanation

Tags: c#

So here is my code:

```
        Console.Write("Insert first array length: ");
        string[] izmers1 = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
        Console.Write("Insert second array length: ");
        string[] izmers2 = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];

        for (int i = 0; i < izmers1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Insert 1.array {0} array value: ", i + 1);
                izmers1[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        for (int j = 0; j < izmers2.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Insert 2.array {0} array value: ", j + 1);
                izmers2[j] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        for (int k = 0; k < izmers1.Length; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1.array {0} value is {1}", k + 1, izmers1[k]);
            }


        for (int p = 0; p < izmers2.Length; p++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("2.array {0} value is {1}", p + 1, izmers2[p]);
            }
```

I need to create a loop or something , that will create combination of array's.
Imagine we entered length 3 and 4.
Then insert some value for each, our output is:

```
     1.array 1.value q
     1.array 2.value w
     1.array 3.value e
     2.array 1.value Q
     2.array 2.value W
     2.array 3.value E
     2.array 4.value R
```

i need to create a combination that will look like this one qQwWeER.
My english is not very good, so i hope someone understand what i need and can explain how to get it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq's [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) along with a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the combined string:

```
    var s = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(izmers1.Length, izmers2.Length)).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, i) => 
        { 
            if (i < izmers1.Length) sb.Append(izmers1[i]); 
            if (i < izmers2.Length) sb.Append(izmers2[i]); 
            return sb; 
        }).ToString();
    }
```

**Update** You need to learn to read Linq and lambda expressions, they are an integral part of the language and are used extensively.  The code I wrote also could be rewritten as follows:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, length = Math.Max(izmers1.Length, izmers2.Length); i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i < izmers1.Length) sb.Append(izmers1[i]);
        if (i < izmers2.Length) sb.Append(izmers2[i]);
    }
    var s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get easier code, like i did? with for or something. I just started to learn c# and this code looks too complex for me at the moment :s

Comment: @naathanz - OK, but please be more specific about your requirements in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
var result =
    String.Join("", Enumerable.Zip(
        izmers1.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", izmers2.Length)),
        izmers2.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("", izmers1.Length)),
        (i1, i2) => i1 + i2));
```

It's worth learning some of these approaches as they can make your coding so much simpler.